# Short Story where something is looking at a man

Tags: story-identification

I am desperate to find the name of a short story I read a few years ago.  it was only about a page and a half long, and it contained two things (unknown what they were) who were looking at different animals, and finally come to something, small and alone.  It is revealed to be the most dangerous of things, and then it is revealed it is a human.  It was striking, and a good short story and I would love to reread it.  Help!

Answer (score 2):

The King of Beasts by Philip Jose Farmer

Comment: This seems to be correct, as we [see in this other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117715/what-is-the-name-of-the-sci-fi-short-story-where-there-is-one-remaining-human-le), but answers to these types of questions are better when they include a synopsis or excerpts that address the question.