# What is the name of the sci Fi short story where there is one remaining human left?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a sci fi short story awhile back that was from the perspective of 'scientists', which we later find out aren't human, who are looking at the last remaining animals of each species (including a lion). There is a plot twist at the end where there is 'the most dangerous of all the species': the human being.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Are there any other details you remember, such as when the story may have been written or approximately when you read it (2 years, 10 years, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [The King of the Beasts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59029) by [Philip José Farmer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?26).

> “Our budget,” he said, “is too limited to re-create all known extinct species. So we bring to life only the higher animals, the beautiful ones that were wantonly exterminated. I’m trying, as it were, to make up for brutality and stupidity. You might say that man struck God in the face every time he wiped out a branch of the animal kingdom.” [...] 
>  The visitor stepped sharply back from the tank. He said, “Then it must be… But you wouldn’t dare!”
>  The biologist nodded.
>  “Yes. It’s a man.”