# Short story about animal resurrection, but the resurrectioner doesn't want to bring back humans who caused the extinction

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I think it's titled "The Beast" but I can't find it under that name.

It's a very short story. I can't remember but I think it's post-apocalyptic.

It's about someone or something  resurrecting the animals, and is scared of resurrecting the humans because their species caused the extinction.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name of the sci Fi short story where there is one remaining human left?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117715/what-is-the-name-of-the-sci-fi-short-story-where-there-is-one-remaining-human-le)

Comment: @Dragan Unfortunately, there's not confirmation from the OP that these are the same two stories. We will have to wait.

Answer (score 9):

As Dragan [says in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149723/short-story-animal-resurrection/149813#comment384947_149723), this has to be ["The King of the Beasts"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59029) (1964) by Philip Jose Farmer. This story has been the subject of a previous story id question: [What is the name of the sci Fi short story where there is one remaining human left?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117715/what-is-the-name-of-the-sci-fi-short-story-where-there-is-one-remaining-human-le) I read it in the anthology [*The Ninth Galaxy Reader*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44730) (1966).

The story is only two pages long - it's almost short enough to post the whole story as an answer if copyright permitted. A biologist is explaining to a visitor how he has been resurrecting extinct species, and showing him all the animals. Finally they reach the last tank:

> The visitor stopped before the last of the tanks.
> ‘Just one?’ he said. ‘What is it?’
> ‘Poor little thing,’ said the biologist, now sad. ‘It will be so alone. But I shall give it all the love I have.’
> ‘Is it so dangerous?’ said the visitor: ‘Worse than elephants, tigers, and bears?’
> ‘I had to get special permission to grow this one,’ said the biologist. His voice quavered.
> The visitor stepped sharply back from the tank. He said, ‘Then it must be... But you wouldn’t dare!’
> The biologist nodded.
> ‘Yes. It’s a man.’

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're thinking of van Vogt's "[The Monster](https://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2008/03/e-van-vogt-monster-aka-resurrection.html)" (1948), (also known as "Resurrection") in which aliens revive various primitive humans, ending, to their sorrow, with the last iteration.

Comment: Enjoy 10k powers!